# AND Logic on 24 Volt Signals

Tags: pcb, sensor, boolean-algebra

What kind of chip and/or plug and play device could handle multi-input boolean logic with 24 volt signals?

I have three sets of 20 <del>reed</del> Hall effect, three-wire switches that each output a 24 Volt signal, and I need to combine them down to simply 3 24 volt signals using AND logic (where the signal is high only if all <del>reed</del> switches in a given set are also high).

I am currently using a PLC, but I think that is way more functionality and price than I need. I thought about powering each one of the reed switches using the signal wire from the previous one, but I sincerely doubt these reed switches can handle the amperage that would need.

Edit: @Transistor You are right, these are three wire Hall magnetic field sensors, not true reed switches.

A = AND(A1, A2, A3, A4...) or rather A = AND( AND(A1, A2), AND(A3, A4)) etc.
The AND logic is the A is high only if all A# are high. The same is true for B, and C.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We need a little more information added into your question. (1) How many contacts per reed switch? 1? (2) Do any of the switches appear in the AND logic for multiple outputs? (3) Can you post your AND logic? (4) If each logic branch could drive a 24 V relay to switch the high current would that suffice?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Diode logic.

Comment: I think I may have misread initially. "*I have three sets of 20 reed switches that each output a 24 V signal ...*" (1) Each set just needs to be ANDed. There is no switch common to two circuits. (2) I'm beginning to suspect that they are not true "reed" switches but possibly 3-wire Hall sensors such as found on pneumatic actuators but erroneously called "reed switches". @Joseph, please clarify in your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @Joseph, "... these are three wire Hall magnetic field sensors, not true reed switches." They're not reed switches at all! See the update to my answer. Note that Imgur is acting up all day so you might not see the schematics until later.

Comment: Are these hall sensors PNP or NPN type?

Answer (score 3):

A 24V AND gate is easy to do with diode logic. For each input of the AND gate connect the anode of a diode to that input. Connect all of the cathodes to together, and connect a pullup resistor from the diode cathodes to 24V. If any input is low the output will be pulled down to about 0.7V. If all of the inputs are at 24V the output will be 24V. Diodes that can handle 24V are quite inexpensive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ5cuN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a schematic of your proposal. Please edit if I've got it wrong but you seem to be describing an **OR** function. The output will be high if *any* input is high.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (as mentioned by @Transistor), and it's also incorrect as OR logic - you should connect all the *anodes* together, with the cathodes going to the inputs.

Comment: @awjlogan: There is no pull-down on the OP's switches so simply reversing the diodes won't work. You'd have to add strong pull-downs on each switch. It all gets to be a bit of a mess of discrete components which is what I'm trying to avoid in my answer. With 60 switches a diode and resistor each requires 120 additional components.

Comment: @Transistor Absolutely, but this answer is fundamentally wrong anyway, don't know why it's got upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLWH0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Standard relay logic. Diode D1 protects the reed switches against arcing when the relay is switched off.*

In the old days this sort of problem was all solved by relay logic. In this example RLY1 is energised when all the required switches are closed.

Depending on the logic this may be enough but if you are using single-contact reed switches then additional relays may or may not be required to give additional contacts. Diodes can also be used so that contacts can be used on several circuits but this depends on your logic.

---

> Edit: @Transistor You are right, these are three wire Hall magnetic field sensors, not true reed switches.

Right-ho. They're not reed switches at all. Start again.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2tIf.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. The problem. You can't daisy-chain too many of these switches before voltage drop becomes an issue and following switches won't work.*

Some of these sensors have a wide operating voltage and low quiescent current. I suggest the following to see what your options are:

- Get the specification (and share it with us). Find out

  - The operating voltage range.
  - The queiescent current (when no magnet near).
  - The no-load on current (magnet near) which will probably be mostly due to the indicator LED, if there is one.
  - The voltage drop between the input and output when on and load present.

With this information you should be able to work out how many you can connect in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWZtL.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. If, for example, the switches will work down to 12 V and the voltage drop across each was less than 1.2 V then ten could be connected in series to drive a 12 V relay. Two chains of these would drive two relays and series connection of their contacts would give an output when all 20 switches are on.*

Note that a downside of this arrangement is that all sensor indicator lamps (if they are fitted) will be off after the first open switch. You will always have to fault find from left to right.

Report back.

Comment: The OP said this will probably not work ...and I think this deviates from the powering system the OP has.

Comment: See the update (when Imgur starts working again).

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like a 3 * 8 input AND would seem to work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVJSn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously the diode input element can be expanded to suit any grouping you like.

Comment: That'll work *if* the switches can pull low. If they really are reed switches they can't. If they're PNP transistor output as I'm beginning to suspect they won't either. Let's see if the OP clarifies as requested.

Comment: @transistor. Not so. If the reed switches apply power to following systems, then the only requirement is that the following system be able to sink 2.4 mA in total. If only one following system is still unpowered then all the 2.4 mA would need to be sunk ….if several are low then the current may be shared. It's the same deal for any solution with a resistive divider.

Comment: Read the question again. I think he's got PNP transistor switches and he's thinking of powering each switch from the PNP output of the previous switch but realises there's a problem but is not sure what it is. He suspects that the power required for all the switches will overload the first one. I suspect that 20 x switch on-voltage drop will be the real problem with this arrangement.

Comment: @Transistor That's not what the OP says, and he seems quite clear. However, the multi input AND gate with diodes will work no matter what the 'switch' is providing the load will sink the required current.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. Did you see his edit of an hour ago? They're PNP switches. I'm still not clear how your circuit would work even with proper reed switches. If there's a load pulling AND 1-8 low how would it ever get pulled high? D1 can't be pulled low by a PNP switch. Am I missing something? Can you show the switches and load on your schematic?

Comment: @Transistor The 24v high is pulled up by the 10k. When the switches (whatever they are) are turned off the load still exists and provides a sink. When the switches ALL turn on the signal is high. When any one of the switches is off then the load sinks the current (2.4mA). How simple can it be?

Comment: Got it. Your proposal requires the addition of a load on each switch which wasn't stated in the original answer. At the moment the load is the PLC input but this will be gone with the new solution. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 7400 series AND and/or NAND gates, cascaded if necessary, and to make your 24V fit its 3V to 5V input range (depending on what family (HC, HCT, LS…)) you use, add voltage dividers to your two 24 V outputs.

On the output, use a (weak) pull up resistor against 24V and an NPN transistor to pull it down. It's an inverter, hence the NAND recommendation.

In a two-input AND function, this would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrkSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It appears to me that 24V is connected directly to the TTL gate when the reed switches closes...is that really what you want?

Comment: My text addresses that. Add a voltage divider as necessary. You're right, though, I could have added that directly. Give me a second.

Comment: Two inputs done. Only 58 more to go. d:^)

Comment: @Transistor I added this *because* I wasn't sure how the "map 20 reeds to 3 outputs" was even supposed to look, logically. And: since such NAND gates (or AND gates) typically come in multi-gate packages, I hoped this would be a good start :) Other than that, the simple concatenation of reed contacts or simple diode logic beats my approach in simplicity by multiple dozens of dB.

Comment: It should be noted that CD4000 series ICs accept voltages up to 15V, so a simple divide-by-two arrangement can be used.  It also needs  less current input than TTL, so higher resistances can be used.  Both of these factors will reduce the power usage of the circuit, so assuming all other things are equal, this is probably the best choice.

Comment: @Jules uuuuh are you from the 70s?  (just kidding, no offense) TTL levels can (and are) actually done these days (mostly) with CMOS technology :) That's where the "C" in the 7400 series families comes from (74HCxxx, 74HCTxxx …). You'll find that the "can use divide-by-two" isn't really an improvement.

Comment: @Jules is right...CD4000 series logic is still available at low cost and is much more tolerant of supply voltage variations than TTL. I think this was a very good suggestion.